# Como passar dados de estrutura para um ficheiro texto?

Tags: c, struct

Eu tenho esta estrutura:

```
struct televisao {
    int id_guit;
    int precodia;
    int preco;
    int estado;
    char nome[20];
};
```

Eu queria pedir ao utilizador para inserir dados desta estrutura e guardar num ficheiro .txt, como consigo? A parte de verificar se o ficheiro existe consigo fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma simples de ter controlo como os dados são escritos no ficheiro é utilizar [`fprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/). Este é idêntico ao `printf` com a diferença que o primeiro parâmetro é para onde vai ser escrita a informação.

Exemplo:

```
FILE *ficheiro = fopen ("teste.txt","w");
struct televisao tv;
//preencher tv com os dados que interessam
fprintf (ficheiro,"%d,%d,%d,%d,%s\n",tv.id_guit, tv.precodia, tv.preco, tv.estado,tv.nome);
fclose (ficheiro);
```

Neste exemplo utilizei `,` como separador, que faz como se tivesse a criar um ficheiro `csv`, no entanto, o formato com que os dados são escritos no ficheiro fica inteiramente ao seu critério.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `fwrite`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
  struct televisao tv;
  FILE *pFile;
  pFile = fopen ("arquivo.bin", "wb");
  fwrite (tv , sizeof(tv), 1, pFile);
  fclose (pFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Leia mais em [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/).